# To be bound by Parsley, a radio, a checkbox and a multiple select input must have either a name or a multiple option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-5

```
parsley.min.self-b8a90165fa8dc989cc7341bb2d53b98e7c0d9271d5e177a2d4b29e600d8b2a29.js?body=1:17 To be bound by Parsley, a radio, a checkbox and a multiple select input must have either a name or a multiple option. jQuery.fn.init [input, context: input]0: inputcontext: inputlength: 1__proto__: Object(0)
```

I have already explored internet, some says it is related with the name or multiple options of html attribute, i have tried everything but still the issue stands out.

Now i am using multiple checkboxes and they all have dynamic name attribute..i tried to set the multiple option but it did not work.

i have used ruby on rails to implement the check_box_tag.

Anyone know how to stop this any way possible please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved adding the attribute "data-parsley-required" and setting value to false. Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" formControlName="example" data-parsley-required="false">
```